# Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in F:\wamp\www\register.php on line 22

Tags: php, mysql

Hey my issue is when I'm encrypting my user's passwords when they register it puts all their information in my data base properly encryption and all but this error pops up

[image: Error Message]

My code is this:

```
<?php

session_start();

if( isset($_SESSION['user_id']) ){
        header("Location: /");
}

require 'database.php';

$message = '';

if( isset($_POST['submit']) ):
        if( !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password']==$_POST['confirm_password']) && !empty($_POST['username']) ):

                // Enter the new user in the database
                $sql = "INSERT INTO users (email, username, password) VALUES (:email, :username, :password)";
                $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

                $stmt->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
                $stmt->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username']);
                $stmt->bindParam(':password', password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT));

                if( $stmt->execute() ):
                        $message = 'Successfully created new user (Dont mind the error :)';
                else:
                        $message = 'Sorry there must have been an issue creating your account';
                endif;
        else:
                $message = 'Please check if all fields are filled in and match.';
        endif;
endif;

?>
```

If anymore code is needed to solve the problem I will post it to help

Answer (score -3, accepted):

on starting of code you should use

```
error_reporting(0);
```

so all strict error are not displayed.

Comment: Thanks because the error is doing nothing but the code b****ing over something

Comment: never hide the error always fix then , error take to much resource of the server and not deliver the desire output , so best practice to solve theme

Comment: @Dagon.. yes but this strict error will not do anything. so it batter to hide them.

Comment: @PMCJohn welcome. just up-vote the answer and accept it.

Comment: @Dagon there isnt really an error all the data is properly entered in the database

Comment: there really is - i can't fathom any one that would find this an acceptable apporach

Answer (score 0):

as per i read your Question you have issue in this line :

```
 $stmt->bindParam(':password', password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT));
```

the function `bindParam` is not support the third parameter so please check that and let me know if this help

thanks

Comment: what would i do in order to fix it in this case?

Comment: the third param should be one of these: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php

Comment: you need to add third parameter in the function like : $passwordenc=""

Comment: thanks but from what i hear this error is a error that doesnt effect anything